# boost_assert that a parameter class implements a certain method

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, assert, compile-time

Suppose you have a certain template that takes a parameter class

```
template <typename ConnectorClass>
struct myClass {

}
```

I want to add a `BOOST_ASSERT_MSG` to validate that `ConnectorClass` implements a certain method of signature

```
returnType MethodName(param1, param2)
```

How should i write the assert condition in this case?

EDIT: since the question does not seem to have a clear solution, i'm posting a sub-question with intermediate results based on some references on the answers
please follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026097/method-compile-time-assertion-still-not-working)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964357/how-to-tell-if-class-contains-a-certain-member-function-in-compile-time

Answer (score 2):

You can't. BOOST_ASSERT_MSG is evaluated during runtime. If the class doesn't have that member, you'll get a compilation error wherever your template expects it.

If your goal is better error messages, look into Boost's Concept Check library. If your goal is to have your template do something different depending on what members are available, look into Boost's `enable_if`.

[Here's an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence/264088#264088).

Comment: hmm, i'm pretty sure that BOOST_ASSERT_MSG is evaluated at compile-time, however i didn't knew about the Concept Check library, worth a check, thanks!

Comment: You may be thinking of BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, and not too picky, you can do this via [__if_exists, a hack extension to Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7wy9xh3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks, good to know. but for now i'm working on OS X & ubuntu only

Comment: @lurscher - better to do it more cleanly anyway, if possible.  There's another discussion here that might be useful: http://programming.itags.org/c-c++/72176/

Answer (score 0):

Look into the various static assertion utilities in Boost. In particular:

- BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT (see docs [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html))
- BOOST_MPL_ASSERT (see docs [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/asserts.html))