# method compile time assertion; still not working

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++11, compile-time, sfinae

I need a easy way to assert inside a template that a template parameter implements a method (*or one of its parent classes*). I've read Concept check library but is hard to find an easy example to do simple checks like this one.

I've tried to follow other posts (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966362/sfinae-to-check-for-inherited-member-functions) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)), which i've modified so i can make it generic for many method types (in my example Foo (methodName) and has_foo (Checker name) will, once working correctly, be wrapped as macro arguments so it can be used for any method)

the code i have for the moment is this one:

```
template <typename TypeToBeChecked, typename Sign>
class has_foo { 
   static_assert( false , "inside root declaration of " "has_foo" );
public: 
   static const bool result = false;
}; 

template <typename TypeToBeChecked , typename R> 
class has_foo < TypeToBeChecked , R(void) > 
{ 
   static_assert( false , "inside specialization of " "has_foo" " for R(void)" ); 
   class yes { char m;};
   class no { yes m[2];};
   struct BaseMixin { R Foo(){} };
   struct Base : public TypeToBeChecked, public BaseMixin {};
   template <typename T, T t> class Helper{};
   template <typename U> static no deduce(U*, Helper<R (BaseMixin::*)(), &U::Foo>* = 0);
   static yes deduce(...);
public: 
   static const bool result = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(deduce((Base*)(0))); 
};

template <typename TypeToBeChecked , typename R , typename ARG1> 
class has_foo< TypeToBeChecked , R(ARG1) >
{ 
   static_assert( false , "inside specialization of " "has_foo" " for R(ARG1)" ); 
   class yes { char m;};
   class no { yes m[2];};
   struct BaseMixin { R Foo(ARG1){} };
   struct Base : public TypeToBeChecked, public BaseMixin {};
   template <typename T, T t> class Helper{};
   template <typename U> 
   static no deduce(U*, Helper<R (BaseMixin::*)(ARG1), &U::Foo>* = 0);
   static yes deduce(...); 
public: 
   static const bool result = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(deduce((Base*)(0))); 
}; 

template <typename TypeToBeChecked , typename R , typename ARG1 , typename ARG2>
class has_foo< TypeToBeChecked , R(ARG1, ARG2) >
{ 
   static_assert( false , "inside specialization of " "has_foo" " for R(ARG1 , ARG2)" );
   class yes { char m;};
   class no { yes m[2];};
   struct BaseMixin { R Foo(ARG1,ARG2){} };
   struct Base : public TypeToBeChecked, public BaseMixin {};
   template <typename T, T t> 
   class Helper{};
   template <typename U> 
   static no deduce(U*, Helper<R (BaseMixin::*)(ARG1,ARG2), &U::Foo>* = 0); 
   static yes deduce(...);
public: 
   static const bool result = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(deduce((Base*)(0)));
};

template< typename Type >
struct Connector
{  
   static_assert( has_foo< Type , int(int, double) >::result , "Type has no Foo method" );
   void Operate() {
      Type t;
      t.Foo(3);
   }
};

struct Bla1 { int Foo(double f) { return (int)f; } };
struct Bla2 { int Foo(int g, double h) { return g+(int)h;} };

int main() 
{
   //Connector< Bla1 > a;
   Connector< Bla2 > b;
};
```

When i compile this example code (g++ 4.4.3 ubuntu with -std=c++0x option so the static_assert is recognized) i get this:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x -o test
test.cpp:72: error: static assertion failed: "inside root declaration of has_foo"
test.cpp:79: error: static assertion failed: "inside specialization of has_foo for R(void)"
test.cpp:93: error: static assertion failed: "inside specialization of has_foo for R(ARG1)"
test.cpp:108: error: static assertion failed: "inside specialization of has_foo for R(ARG1 , ARG2)"
```

wait just right there, (notice that Connector< Bla1 > a is commented) my first question is:

1) am i right to assume that if the assertion is being evaluated, the containing template is being instantiated?

EDIT: answered by GMan: the static_assert is evaluated during parsing, and not when the template is instantiated. Replacing false with sizeof(TypeToBeChecked)==0 makes it bound to compile-time

2) am i right to assume that since the static assert inside Connector template class is instantiating has_foo with int(int, double) signature, then the single-parameter and parameterless specializations should NOT be instantiated? whats wrong with my assumptions?

EDIT: this assumption is right but now that i fixed according to 1) answer, the instantiation process is now behaving as expected

3) if i uncomment the Connector< Bla1 > a line, i would expect it to fail (since Bla1 only has a Foo with a single parameter signature. However it is not. Any idea what might be wrong? specially taking in consideration the first linked post

Comment: The static asserts will always trigger. `false` is false, regardless of anything you could possibly do, so the compiler must trigger it then and there. If you want it to be dependent, do something like `sizeof(TypeToBeChecked) == 0`, which is both false and dependent.

Comment: interesting, so the static_assert is evaluated at parse-time, rather than compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account also the comments on the answer in the first linked question ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966362/sfinae-to-check-for-inherited-member-functions/1967183#1967183)), your template checks if there is a member `Foo`, but it does not check the signature of that member.

To check the signature, you need code like this (checks for `operator()` that can be invoked with specified arguments; reproduced from [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/msg/e5fbc9305539f699) usenet post on comp.lang.c++.moderated by Roman.Perepelitsa@gmail.com):

```
template <typename Type>
class has_member
{
   class yes { char m;};
   class no { yes m[2];};

   struct BaseMixin
   {
     void operator()(){}
   };

   struct Base : public Type, public BaseMixin {};

   template <typename T, T t>  class Helper{};

   template <typename U>
   static no deduce(U*, Helper<void (BaseMixin::*)(), &U::operator()>*
= 0);
   static yes deduce(...);

public:
   static const bool result = sizeof(yes) == sizeof(deduce((Base*)
(0)));

};

namespace details
{
   template <typename type>
   class void_exp_result
   {};

   template <typename type, typename U>
   U const& operator,(U const&, void_exp_result<type>);

   template <typename type, typename U>
   U& operator,(U&, void_exp_result<type>);

   template <typename src_type, typename dest_type>
   struct clone_constness
   {
     typedef dest_type type;
   };

   template <typename src_type, typename dest_type>
   struct clone_constness<const src_type, dest_type>
   {
     typedef const dest_type type;
   };

}

template <typename type, typename call_details>
struct is_call_possible
{
private:
   class yes {};
   class no { yes m[2]; };

   struct derived : public type
   {
     using type::operator();
     no operator()(...) const;
   };

   typedef typename details::clone_constness<type, derived>::type
derived_type;

   template <typename T, typename due_type>
   struct return_value_check
   {
     static yes deduce(due_type);
     static no deduce(...);
     static no deduce(no);
     static no deduce(details::void_exp_result<type>);
   };

   template <typename T>
   struct return_value_check<T, void>
   {
     static yes deduce(...);
     static no deduce(no);
   };

   template <bool has, typename F>
   struct impl
   {
     static const bool value = false;
   };

   template <typename arg1, typename r>
   struct impl<true, r(arg1)>
   {
     static const bool value =
       sizeof(
            return_value_check<type, r>::deduce(
             (((derived_type*)0)->operator()(*(arg1*)0),
details::void_exp_result<type>())
                         )
            ) == sizeof(yes);

   };

   // specializations of impl for 2 args, 3 args,..
public:
   static const bool value = impl<has_member<type>::result,
call_details>::value;

};
```

Usage example:

```
struct Foo
{
   void operator()(double) const {}
   void operator()(std::string) const {}

};

int main()
{
   STATIC_ASSERT((is_call_possible<Foo, void(double)>::value));
   STATIC_ASSERT((is_call_possible<Foo, void(int)>::value));
   STATIC_ASSERT((is_call_possible<Foo, void(const char *)>::value));
   STATIC_ASSERT((!is_call_possible<Foo, void(void *)>::value));

}
```