# Member-function pointers and phantom classes

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, phantom-reference

I've been messing about with member-function pointers in relation to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3957348/15161). In the code below I call methods on a class (B) that change a variable (count) in it, but I never make an instance of this class. Why does this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class A;
typedef int (A::*MEMFUNC)(int, int);

#define HANDLER(aclass, aproc) (MEMFUNC)(&aclass::aproc)

enum
{
    ADD=1,
    MUL,
    SUB,
    DIV
};

class B
{
    int count;
public:
    B() : count(0) {}
    ~B() {}
    int multiply(int x, int y) { count++; return x*y*count; }
    int divide(int x, int y) { count++; if (y!=0) return (x/y)*count; else return 0; }
};

class A
{
    std::map< int, MEMFUNC > funcs;
public:
    A() { AddLocals(); }
    ~A() {}
    int CallLocal(int nID, int x, int y)
    {
        MEMFUNC f = funcs[nID];
        if (f) return (this->*f)(x, y);
        else return 0;
    }
    void AddLocals()
    {
        Add(ADD, HANDLER(A, plus));
        Add(MUL, HANDLER(B, multiply));
        Add(SUB, HANDLER(A, subtract));
        Add(DIV, HANDLER(B, divide));
    }
    void Add(int nID, MEMFUNC f) { funcs[nID] = f; }
    int plus(int x, int y) { return x+y; }
    int subtract(int x, int y) { return x-y; }

};

int main()
{
    A aA;
    int a,b,c,d;

    a = aA.CallLocal(ADD,8,2);
    b = aA.CallLocal(MUL,8,2);
    c = aA.CallLocal(SUB,8,2);
    d = aA.CallLocal(DIV,8,2);

    std::cout << "a = " << a << "\n" 
              << "b = " << b << "\n" 
              << "c = " << c << "\n" 
              << "d = " << d << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

(sorry, me again, but this member-function pointers are making me itch)

Comment: Any chance you could simplify this code?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing your code with a much simpler example.  By all means rollback if you don't like it...

Comment: It doesn't work. It just looks like it works. There's a huge difference.

Comment: @Oli: there are two things that I want to point out depending on the answers: one is using 'this' to call external members, the other is that the incremented 'count' retains it's value, meaning that B is somehow instantiated and kept between two unrelated calls. But thanks for the thought.

Comment: @jalf: works on debian using gcc ...

Comment: @slashmais: Yeah, my code retained all that, but got rid of the `#define`, the `enum`, the `map`, the extraneous layers of function calls, the destructors, etc.  It's always best to post a *minimal* code example.

Comment: @slashmais: No, it just looks like it works.

Comment: @Oli: then put it in an answer & explain why it 'looks like it works'

Comment: @slashmais: There's no point in me creating a separate answer, because Alf's is the correct one.

Comment: @slashmais: no, it *looks like it works* on debian using gcc. As @Alfs answer points out, it is undefined behavior. That means it might *sometimes* do the right thing, or perhaps, *look like* it does the right thing, while simultanously corrupting other memory somewhere that's going to trip you up later. But it also means that you have no guarantee it's still going to work the *next* time you run your program. So it just looks like it works. It only works if you can trust it to *keep* working.

Comment: Yep, you lot are right, visitor seems to be onto something more useful than UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is just undefined behavior. For example, I get that `b = 2083899728` and `d = -552766888`.

The persistent thing you are manipulating is most likely an int's worth of bytes in the map instance of A (because if the object were indeed a B, then that's the offset where the `count` member would be located.

In my stdlib implementation, the first member of map is the comparison function, in this case an instance of `std::less<int>`. Its size is 1, but there must be unused padding bytes after that to align the other members of map. That is, (at least) the first four bytes of this instantiation of `std::map` contains just garbage that is not used for anything (std::less doesn't have data members and doesn't store state, it just takes space in the map). That would explain why the code doesn't crash - it is modifying a part of the map instance which doesn't affect the functioning of the map.

Add more data members in B before `count`, and now `count++` will affect crucial parts of the map's internal representation and you can get a crash.

Comment: Okay, done that & getting the same type of results as you - your explanation makes sense. Next question: where does it find the code that gets executed?

Comment: At machine level it's just bytes and offsets. The machine basically interprets a call to `B::multiply` as "increment an integer at offset 0 (as `count` is the first member) from the `this` pointer, then multiply it by the values of the function arguments and return the result". Except you don't have a B instance, and the bytes it uses are not really the `count` member of a B instance.

Answer (score 8):

Your cast in the `HANDLER` macro def tells the compiler "Shut up! I know what I'm doing!".

So the compiler shuts up.

You still have Undefined Behavior, but one property of UB is that in some cases it does what you'd naïvely expect, or what you'd want it to do.

But don't be surprised if such code crashes, or causes crashes or mysterious incorrect result in apparently totally unrelated code.

Or, for example, causes nasal demons to fly out your nose.

Cheers & hth.

Comment: LOL, yes, I'm wondering why using the this-pointer in A successfully calls members in B. 'T'is passing strange ...

Comment: The function pointers should be 'wild', but they're calling the correct code. Your answer does not explain this.

Comment: @slashmais: In practice, the "correct" code gets executed, and it returns the "correct" result, because the function has the same signature as the typedef.  But it will also corrupt the stack without telling you.

Comment: @slashmais: The answer is entirely correct. Your code is unsafely casting a member function of `B` to a member function of `A`, then calling it on an instance of `A`. Treating an object of one type as an object of an incompatible type gives undefined behaviour, which could do anything at all. What it's almost certainly doing here is corrupting `aA.funcs`, which could be harmless, or could cause all kinds of bad behaviour. You should avoid casts unless you need them and can prove that they're correct, and avoid C-style casts like the plague - this question is a good example of why.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: visitor came up with the same answer, what remains now is where does it find the code it executes? might it be that, since it is such simple functions, that they got inlined?

Comment: @slashmais: We're in the realms of undefined behaviour, so there's no guaranteed mechanism for finding the code. However, the member function pointer probably points to the expected code; it's just called with `this` pointing to an object of the wrong type. But there's no guarantee that another compiler will do the same thing; your code is invalid, and its behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

C-casting lets you get away with all sorts of horrid behaviour but doesn't mean it's ok to do it so simply don't.

Get rid of your macro completely and do not cast. You can probably use boost::function and boost::bind to get the behaviour you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invoking *undefined behaviour* by trying to call a member of class B using an object of class A.
We can try to explain how the compiler can come to the behaviour you have observed, but there is no guarantee that you will get the same behaviour if you change anything (add/remove a member, change compiler settings or use a different compiler).

With the cast in the `HANDLER` macro, you are telling the compiler not to warn you about the use of incompatible types but just to do as you tell it to. In this case, you tell the compiler to reinterpret the address of a member of any class as being the address of a member of class A.

When you later try to call, for example, `B::multiply`, that function does not know that it is not working on an object of class B, so it will happily clobber the bytes of `aA` that would correspond to the `B::count` member if it had been a `B` object. Most likely, these bytes are actually being used by `A::funcs`, but apparently not for anything critical. If you change class A to:

```
class A
{
    int count;
    std::map< int, MEMFUNC > funcs;
public:
    A() : count(0) { AddLocals(); }
    ~A() {}
    int CallLocal(int nID, int x, int y)
    {
        MEMFUNC f = funcs[nID];
        if (f) return (this->*f)(x, y);
        else return 0;
    }
    int Count()
    {
        return count;
    }
    void AddLocals()
    {
        Add(ADD, HANDLER(A, plus));
        Add(MUL, HANDLER(B, multiply));
        Add(SUB, HANDLER(A, subtract));
        Add(DIV, HANDLER(B, divide));
    }
    void Add(int nID, MEMFUNC f) { funcs[nID] = f; }
    int plus(int x, int y) { return x+y; }
    int subtract(int x, int y) { return x-y; }

};
```

then printing the result of `aA.Count()` at various places might show the effect.

The compiler is calling the expected function, because they are non-virtual member functions.
The only difference between non-member functions and non-virtual member functions is in the hidden argument that feeds the `this` pointer in a member function. So, if you take the address of a non-virtual member function, you will get a fixed address that is distinct for every function.
If the member functions had been virtual, then the compiler would, most likely, have returned the index into the v-table as a pointer for that function (together with some kind of indication that it is a v-table offset). Then the code can determine at the call-site if it can do a direct call to the member function or if it needs to do an indirect call through the v-table of the object the function is called on.