# check if member exists and invoke it or do nothing

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, sfinae

I have one template class with init() method which have to invoke  subclass method if it exists. Method init() of Base class invokes forever.

```
template <class T>
class Base
{

   template<typename... Args>
   void init(Args... args);

   T subj;

   explicit Base() { subj = new T(); }
}


template<typename... Args>
Base<T>::init(Args... args)
{
    invoke_if_exists<&T::init,subj>(args); // <-- that moment
}
```

There is needed to implement invoke_if_exists template. The algorithm should be as code like that

```
if ( method_exists(T::init) )
{
     subj->init(Args...);
}
```

I need it to be wrapped into template

Thank you so much.

[update]:

Let I try to explain little widely.

```
class Foo
{
// ... and there is no init()
};

class Right
{
    void init() { ... }
 /// ...
}


auto a = new Base<Foo>();
auto b = new Base<Right>();

a->init();  // there is no call for Foo::init();
b->init();  // there is correct call for Right::init();
```

I want to use `invoke_if_exists<>` not only with init() method, it could be any.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature

Comment: Only one thing: template should be expanded only if method exists, otherwise empty code 'cause we'll get compiler error like "error: SomeClass has no member named 'method'"

Comment: `invoke_if_exists<&T::init,subj>(args...);` (your forgot the expansion)

Comment: @MadScienceDreams not quite, as you don't need to match exact signatures here.

Comment: You can look at the example in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957348/what-is-the-practical-use-of-pointers-to-member-functions maybe the methods I use there will be of use ...

Comment: @slashmais you kinda do, you need T::init to be a void T::init(Args...).

Comment: @MadScienceDreams no, you need it to accept `Args`.  You don't need its signature to be exactly `Args`.  As an example, if someone calls `init(7)`, you might be surprised that `T::init(long)` wouldn't be called, and if you look for exact signatures, that is exactly what would happen.  Ditto with return type.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: I've been reading your link to ../87372/.. and it's fascinating (also makes me wonder how many raw beginners in C++ throw their hands up at the complexity/obscurity and walk away ;)

Answer (score 3):

A data and type sink, which take types and data, and do nothing with them:

```
struct sink {
  template<typename... Us>
  void operator()(Us&&... us) const {}
};
template<typename... Ts>
struct type_sink:std::true_type {};
```

we then create a `template` `invoke_init_if_exists`, which takes a target type `T` and a set of arguments, and if `T*->init` can be invoked with these arguments, does so.  Otherwise, it throws the stuff into the data sink above:

```
template<typename T,typename ArgTypes,typename=void>
struct invoke_init_if_exists:sink {};
template<typename T,template<typename...>class Pack,typename... Args>
struct invoke_init_if_exists<T,
  Pack<Args...>,
  typename std::enable_if< type_sink<
    decltype( std::declval<T*>()->init( std::declval<Args>()... ) )
  >::value >::type
>
{
  void operator()( T* target, Args&&... args ) const {
    target->init( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
};
```

We then use this to implement your `init` method:

```
template<typename... Args>
Base<T>::init(Args&&... args)
{
  invoke_init_if_exists<T, type_sink<Args...>>()(&subj, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

where we create our helper class, which is either a `sink` or something that forwards to `init` depending on if the call to `init` is valid.

We end up having to do something like this because you cannot name the token `T::init` with validity unless `T` already has a method `init`.  So we have to write a custom class that does the `T::init` lookup in a SFINAE context, and if it fails falls back to doing nothing.

Comment: Be aware that this might be error prone: If you supply an invalid set of arguments for a type `T` that *does* have an `init` function, you'll get no compile-time error. (As opposed to a SFINAE check if `init` exists at all and then calling it with the provided arguments.)

Comment: @DyP yep.  But in C++, you cannot in general determine if there is a method `init` on a type `T`.  You can ask "is there a method `init` with exactly the signature of `R(Args...)`", or you can ask "is there a method `init` that can be called with `Args...` and returns something convertible to `R`", or linear combinations thereof.  You can also ask "is there a single, solitary, non-overridden, `T::init` non-`template` method."  Each has its own issues.

Comment: So if I truly understand I can't define template without determining specific class method and then explicit call of it `target->init( ... )`. I mean, is there no way to forward object and the pointer on to its method using your invoke template?

Comment: @Shozabred the above will invoke `init` with no args if there is an `init` with no args in type type `T`.  You have to write a custom helper for each name of function (you cannot write `invoke_if_exists<T::foo,blah>`, but you can write `invoke_foo_if_exists<blah>`).